# How to Embed data (PDF Base 64) in angular 6 component

Tags: html, angular, embed

In my application in angular 6,  I am showing Data(Report) in new window as follows.
*** result contains Base64 data***

```
if (result != null) {    
          const pdfWindow = window.open("");    
          pdfWindow.document.write("<html<head><title>Pathology Report</title><style>body{margin: 0px;}iframe{border-width: 0px;}</style></head>");    
          pdfWindow.document.write("<body><embed width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +    
              encodeURI(result) + "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0'></embed></body></html>")
```

Now what I want to do is like, I want to embed this data(result) in my angular component in tag.
My html code is as follows

```
<iframe [src]="PathReportString"></iframe>
```

and component.ts code is

```
this.PathReportString = (this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(result) as any).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
```

But it shows error "unsafe value used in a resource URL context".
The result get displayed properly in new window but when try to embed, it shows error.
How to embed data. Also my data is base64.
What is going wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It works. I wrote code in .html file as

```
 <iframe id="ifrm" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

and in component.ts file code is like,

```
 this.PathReportString = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + (this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(result) as any).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
      
top.document.getElementById('ifrm').setAttribute("src", this.PathReportString);
```

Answer (score 1):

please add data:application/pdf;base64, before the base64 String

```
<iframe [src]="data:application/pdf;base64, PathReportString"></iframe>
```

Comment: it shows error. "Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
        Statement: application/pdf;base64, PathReportString"

Comment: PathReportString is it a base64 string?

Comment: I see, would you please add single quotes between the double quotes. 
please add data:application/pdf;base64, before the base64 String

<iframe [src]="'data:application/pdf;base64, PathReportString'"></iframe>

Comment: tried as you said. shows error "unsafe value used in a resource URL context"